# rolling a superdie

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

Eight standard six-sided dice are glued together to form a 2×2×2 "superdie". (The way the dice are glued together is chosen randomly.) This superdie is then rolled, and the number of dots that appear on the upper face is counted.Find the probability that the total number of dots is equal to 7. The order of the smaller dices is creating a problem for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I read it, if the way the dice are glued together is truly random, then the problem breaks down to the probability of rolling a seven with 4 dice.

Which can be solved with stars and bars to figure out how many rolls of a seven are possible.  After allotting one pip to each of the 4 dice, how many ways can the remaining 3 pips necessary to roll a 7 be allocated to the 4 dice?  ${{3+4-1}\choose 3}=20$.

Similar to: How many solutions for $a+b+c+d=7$ if $a,b,c,d>0$

And $6^4$ would be the total number of rolls possible with those four dice.